# Atualizar versão do Entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, atualização

Acabei de atualizar minha versão do .Net 3.5 para 4.5.1.

O meu Entity Framework estava na versão 3.5, eu queria saber se ele já atualiza para a versão mais nova depois da troca de *framework*.

Comment: Você já percebeu que as perguntas e respostas devem contar apenas perguntas e respostas? Não incluímos textos que podem ser consideramos apenas ruído no que é mais importante. Isto inclui saudações e agradecimentos. As perguntas e respostas devem servir mais ou menos como a FAQ para todas as pessoas. Não é uma postagem sua para outra pessoa. Por acaso você está postando uma pergunta que deve servir para todos. Não somos um fórum ou rede social. As **perguntas** e **respostas** devem reinar absolutas.

Comment: Exatamente, então não transforme ela em uma coisa que pareça ser só sua. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade creio ser impossível que seu Entity Framework esteja na versão 3.5, até porque [a versão mais antiga distribuída é a 4.1.10311](https://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework).

De qualquer forma, para atualizar, vá em View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console e digite:

> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.1

Isto deve atualizar seu Entity Framework para a versão estável mais recente na data desta resposta.

Comment: Aparentemente faltam mais configurações, e algumas coisas devem ter ficado defasadas.